# Storm Supervisor can't find KafkaSpout class

Tags: java, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

I'm writing a dockerized Java 9 Spring application using Apache Storm 1.1.2, Apache Kafka 0.10, Zookeeper, and Docker Compose.

My topology was entirely working on a local cluster inside of my dockerized service but now that I'm moving it to a production cluster there is an issue.

My service to create an submit topologies to the Storm cluster seems to be working fine and the code looks mostly like this inside of a PostConstruct

```
KafkaSpoutConfig<String,String> spoutConf = 
KafkaSpoutConfig.builder("kafka:9092", "topic")
  .setProp(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "my-group-id")
  .setProp(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, MyDeserializer.class)
.build();

TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
builder.setSpout("kafkaSpoutId", new KafkaSpout<String,String>(spoutConf));
builder.setBolt("boltId", new MyBolt()).shuffleGrouping("kafkaSpoutId");

Config conf = new Config();
conf.setNumWorkers(2);
conf.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS, List.of("zookeeper"));
conf.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_PORT, 2181);

conf.put(Config.NIMBUS_SEEDS, List.of("nimbus"));
conf.put(Config.NIMBUS_THRIFT_PORT, 6627);

System.setProperty("storm.jar","/opt/app.jar");
StormSubmitter.submitTopology("topology-id", conf, builder.createTopology());
```

And my docker compose file looks like this.

```
version: "2.1"

services:
  my-service:
  image: my-service
  mem_limit: 4G
  memswap_limit: 4G
  networks:
    - default
  environment:
    - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local

nimbus:
  image: storm:1.1.2
  container_name: nimbus
  command: >
    storm nimbus
      -c storm.zookeeper.servers="[\"zookeeper\"]"
      -c nimbus.seeds="[\"nimbus\"]"
  networks:
    - default
  ports:
    - 6627:6627

supervisor:
  image: storm:1.1.2
  container_name: supervisor
  command: >
    storm supervisor
      -c storm.zookeeper.servers="[\"zookeeper\"]"
      -c nimbus.seeds="[\"nimbus\"]"
  networks:
    - default
  depends_on:
    - nimbus
  links:
    - nimbus
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 6700
    - 6701
    - 6702
    - 6703

ui:
  image: storm:1.1.2
  command: storm ui -c nimbus.seeds="[\"nimbus\"]"
  networks: 
    - default
  ports:
    - 8081:8080

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: myNetwork
```

All of the containers are up. In the UI I can see the topology created in the post construct but no Kafka messages are being processed and the bolt which should be using local Kafka producers to produce the aggregates is not publishing.

In the supervisor container at `/logs/worker-artifact/topology-id****/6700/worker.log` I can see two exceptions repeated.

The first one (and more important I think) is `ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.KafkaSpout`

and the second exception is `org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:6700`

***UPDATE***

Unfortunately, I can't post my whole pom but here are my Storm dependencies

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
        <version>${storm.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-kafka-client</artifactId>
        <version>${storm.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and here is a my spring-boot-maven-plugin. I though adding the configuration to make the jar that is copied to my container non-executable would do the trick. When I examine the jar in the container, it looks to have the lines of the dependency included jar but with a ton of gibberish characters as well

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <executable>false</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is most of my dockerfile

```
FROM ${docker.repository}/openjdk:9.0.1

EXPOSE 80 1099

WORKDIR /opt

ENTRYPOINT ["java", \
    "-Dinfo.serviceName=${project.artifactId}", \
    "-Dinfo.serviceVersion=${project.version}"]

CMD ["-jar", "app.jar"]

LABEL VERSION="${project.version}" DESCRIPTION="${project.description}"

COPY ${project.build.finalName}-exec.jar /opt/app.jar
```

Comment: Please post your pom. I'm guessing there's something wrong with the way you're packaging your topology jar, since the KafkaSpout class is apparently missing at runtime.

Comment: Thank you! Just added it. That's what I'm thinking too but I don't know of another way to get my fat jar into the container for Storm to reference the classes from other than what I'm doing

Comment: I'm not familiar with the spring-boot-maven-plugin, but going by the examples, it looks like you might be missing an execution of the repackage goal https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/maven-plugin/usage.html. Other than that, try building the jar and opening it up with a zip tool. You should be able to tell if the org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.KafkaSpout class is in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The issue is I was forming a non-executable jar but not a real fat jar. I added the following pulgins to my pom

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Next I changed the System property to 
`System.setProperty("storm.jar", "/opt/storm.jar");`

and added the following line to my Dockerfile

`COPY ${project.build.finalName}-jar-with-dependencies.jar /opt/storm.jar`

Finally I would first run `mvn comiple assembly:single` then copy the project jar with dependencies from target/ to target/docker-ready like *from project dir* `cp target/project-jar-with-dependencies.jar target/docker-ready/` and finally run `mvn verify docker:build`